# curl -X GET -I -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" does not bypass

Tags: curl, nginx, cache-control, no-cache

I am doing the following

```
$ curl -X GET -I -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" https:/myserver/myimage.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 22:55:31 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 37502
Connection: keep-alive
Etag: "wzsdm-1434973626-37502-1204291434"
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public
Expires: Wed, 01 Jul 2015 22:43:01 GMT
X-Proxy-Cache: HIT
```

Where I expect to get the following instead

```
X-Proxy-Cache: BYPASS
```

My configuration on Nginx is as follow:

```
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|pdf|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ { 
      proxy_cache my_zone;
      add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

      include proxy_params;
      proxy_pass http://my-backend;
   }
```

Is there any configuration I could have missed out?

Comment: I guess you need http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_bypass. `Cache-Control` header is for browser, not for server.

Comment: Yes I know "Cache-Control: no-cache" is for browser. In Chrome, it send 'Cache-Control:max-age=0' instead. 

I've included proxy_cache_bypass and it doesn't BYPASS the cache.

Comment: And what did you include?

Comment: I did not include anything (apart from the sites-enabled ofcourse). My nginx was install off apt-get.

Comment: Show full nginx config.

Comment: I don't see any `proxy_cache_bypass` in your current config

Answer (score 2):

By default, Nginx's cache does not honour the `Cache-Control:no-cache` request header, nor the `Pragma:no-cache` request header. You must explicitly configure Nginx to bypass the cache and pass the request onto the origin server when the user agent sends these request headers.

Add the following lines to your configuration file:

```
proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
```

[From Nginx's caching guide](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/):

> How Does NGINX Handle the Pragma Header?
>
> The Pragma:no‑cache header is added by clients to bypass all
>   intermediary caches and go straight to the origin server for the
>   requested content. NGINX does not honor the Pragma header by default,
>   but you can configure the feature with the following
>   proxy_cache_bypass directive:

Comment: From the docs:  If at least one value of the string parameters is not empty and is not equal to “0” then the response will not be taken from the cache.  So it doesn't care about the content of the header, any non empty/zero Pragma or Cache-Control request header would trigger a BYPASS.  Browsers normally set "no-cache" when doing a hard refresh.